# Find a divergent sequence such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} |x_{k+p} - x_k| = 0$ for any positive integer p.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Give an example of a sequence that diverges and such that for any positive integer $p$:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} |x_{k+p} - x_k| = 0$$

I was thinking about the sequence

$$x_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n}$$

It is divergent, but I am not sure if the condition holds because by limit definition

$$|x_{k+p} - x_k| < \varepsilon$$

But this equals to:

$$x_{k+p} - x_k = \sum_{q=k+1}^{k+p} \frac{1}{q}$$

But I am stuck stuck at this step. Can you please tell me whether this sequence is indeed the right one or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's think carefully about the nesting of quantifiers:

- For every integer $p$:

  - For every $\epsilon>0$:

    - There exists a $K$ (that can depend on both $p$ and $\epsilon$):

      - So that for every $k>K$:

        - $|x_{k+p}-x_k| < \epsilon$.

So our strategy will be the following: let's try to prove some kind of bound on $|x_{k+p}-x_k|$ in terms of $p$, and then use that bound to cook up a formula for $K$ that works.

Well, we have
$$|x_{k+p}-x_k| = \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+p}\frac{1}{i}.$$
Writing down this sum in closed form seems tricky! But we can easily write down a bound, by using the fact that all terms of the sum are less than $\frac{1}{k}$:
$$|x_{k+p}-x_k| = \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+p}\frac{1}{i} < \frac{p}{k}.$$

For every $\epsilon > 0$, we need $|x_{k+p} - x_k| < \epsilon$. This will be true if
$$\frac{p}{k} < \epsilon$$
or
$$k > \frac{p}{\epsilon}.$$

This tells us how to pick $K$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

As noticed you are done indeed

$$x_{k+p} - x_k = \sum_{q=k+1}^{k+p} \frac{1}{q}\le \frac{p}{k+1} \to 0$$

As a simpler example let consider instead

$$x_k=\log k \to \infty$$

such that

$$|x_{k+p} - x_k|=\left|\log{\left(1+\frac p k\right)} \right|\to 0$$

Comment: Did you check for duplicates? All these examples (and more) have been given before.

Comment: @MartinR Yes I did, I see now your duplicate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to find such a sequence where $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} |x_{k + 1} - x_k| = 0$.

This is because $|x_{k + p} - x_k| \leq \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{p - 1} |x_{k + i + 1} - x_{k + i}|$ by the triangle inequality. So we see that $\lim\limits_{p \to \infty} |x_{k + p} - x_k| \leq \sum\limits_{i = 0}^p \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} |x_{k + i + 1} - x_{k + i}| = 0$.

I would personally take $x_i = \sqrt{x}$. Note that $x_{k + 1} - x_k = \sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k} = (\sqrt{k + 1} - \sqrt{k}) \frac{\sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k + 1} + \sqrt{k}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k + 1}}$, so $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} |x_{k + 1} -  x_k| = 0$.

You could alternately take $x_k = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k \frac{1}{i}$ and use the well-known divergence of the harmonic series.